# How can I change the size of the timer in ngx-material-timepicker?

Tags: angular8, angular9

My application is both a mobile and desktop application and in some phones the size of timer does not fits in the screen.
I am able to change the size of timer in console by setting the height property but not in the CSS or .js file.